# Excel Vlookup Fail Does not recognize letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to do a vlookup that looks at different letter ratings (AAA,+AA,AA,AA-,A+,A,A-,etc.) and give that letter rating a numeric value from 0 to 100 that is in an array in another worksheet. But for some reason, my vlookup doesnt seem to recognize the letter rating either in the main worksheet or in the reference table with the numeric scale in it. I'm not sure whats wrong. Please help!

I've attached my 2 worksheets in the following example:
[https://expirebox.com/download/eacc6...95dbbe1a1.html](http://Hi%20guys,%20%20I'm%20trying%20to%20do%20a%20vlookup%20that%20looks%20at%20different%20letter%20ratings%20(AAA,+AA,AA,AA-,A+,A,A-,etc.)%20and%20give%20that%20letter%20rating%20a%20numeric%20value%20from%200%20to%20100%20that%20is%20in%20an%20array%20in%20another%20worksheet.%20But%20for%20some%20reason,%20my%20vlookup%20doesnt%20seem%20to%20recognize%20the%20letter%20rating%20either%20in%20the%20main%20worksheet%20or%20in%20the%20reference%20table%20with%20the%20numeric%20scale%20in%20it.%20I'm%20not%20sure%20whats%20wrong.%20Please%20help!%20%20I've%20attached%20my%202%20worksheets%20in%20the%20following%20example:%20https://expirebox.com/download/eacc6...95dbbe1a1.html%20%20Thanks%20for%20the%20help!%20%20Gabriel)

Thanks for the help!

Gabriel

P.S. The Vlookup is in column U of the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to open the link you provided.

TheSilkCode

Comment: This response would be best posted as a comment, since it does not provide an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah Sorry @Ron Rosenfeld- I don't think I had enough cred points or whatever to be able to post a comment at that point. Will Do going forward.

Comment: The link does not work, as it starts with: "http://Hi%20guys,%20%20I'm%20trying%" then you need to correct it.